# ExcelPackage excel file load collection

Tags: vb.net, openxml, excelpackage

I have been using openxml from excelpackage to manipulate excel spreadsheet and I am stumbled on a function called ***LoadFromCollection***.

Here is a sample code to understand.

```
 Dim ws As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet
 ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets(tableName)
 Dim OutRange = ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromCollection(newList, True)
```

My question is what this method is doing and what is the correct way to use this function.

Is there any clear documentation?

### **Edit**

Ok from documentation I understand a collection `IEnumerable<T>` is loaded from top left row of the range.But how does it map with the cells?

Suppose I have 4-5 custom properties in `Type T`.So how does the cells are filled?Is it like

1. A1 - 1st Property
2. B1 - 2nd Property

Need more precise explanation.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase/M/LoadFromCollection(T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this link : [LoadFromCollection method implementation](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/0d53d2f885857f6cdf52ef940baae1024e4b301b/EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase.cs#L1694).

According to the source code it should start from Cell `A1` and in the columns of 1st row it should write public properties names of type `T`. Next it would create corresponding rows to each element in `IEnumerable<T>` collection with actual values of properties in columns.